# Understanding C++ typecasts with smart pointers

Tags: c++, casting, c++20, smart-pointers

When I played with some side aspects of class inheritance and smart pointers, I discovered something about modern C++ type casts which I don't understand. I'm sure there is a logical explanation and hope someone could provide it.

Consider these classes:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual ~base() = default;
    void Func() const {}
};

class derived : public base
{
private:
    using base::Func; // makes base::Func inaccessible
};
```

The "using" in `class derived` makes access to `base::Func` through a `derived*` impossible, but through a `base*` the function can still be accessed.

Now, smart pointers come into play. Of course, `base:Func` has the same accessibility rule.

```
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<derived> pShDer{ make_shared<derived>() };
// error C2248: 'derived::Func': cannot access private member declared in class 'derived'
//pShDer->Func();

((shared_ptr<base>&)pShDer)->Func(); // ok
// error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'std::shared_ptr<derived>' to 'std::shared_ptr<base> &'
//static_cast<shared_ptr<base>&>(pShDer)->Func();
reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<base>&>(pShDer)->Func(); // ok
static_cast<shared_ptr<base>const &>(pShDer)->Func(); // ok
reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<base>const &>(pShDer)->Func(); // ok
```

The idea is, I don't construct a temporary `shared_ptr<base>` and destroy it when the line of code ends, but rather I want the compiler to treat the existing `shared_ptr<derived>` as if it were a pointer to base.

Playing the game with `unique_ptr` changes the situation a bit:

```
unique_ptr<derived> pUnDer{ make_unique<derived>() };
// error C2248: 'derived::Func': cannot access private member declared in class 'derived'
//pUnDer->Func();

((unique_ptr<base>&)pUnDer)->Func(); // ok
// error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<derived,std::default_delete<derived>>' to 'std::unique_ptr<base,std::default_delete<base>> &'
// static_cast and safe_cast to reference can only be used for valid initializations or for lvalue casts between related classes
//static_cast<unique_ptr<base>&>(pUnDer)->Func();
reinterpret_cast<unique_ptr<base>&>(pUnDer)->Func(); // ok
// error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<derived,std::default_delete<derived>>' to 'const std::unique_ptr<base,std::default_delete<base>> &'
// Reason: cannot convert from 'std::unique_ptr<derived,std::default_delete<derived>>' to 'const std::unique_ptr<base,std::default_delete<base>>'
// No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
//static_cast<unique_ptr<base>const&>(pUnDer)->Func();
reinterpret_cast<unique_ptr<base>const&>(pUnDer)->Func(); // ok
```

Obviously the C-style cast work always, and so does the `reinterpret_cast`. But why does the `static_case` compile in only one of the cases (and not in all or none)? And what is the (Microsoft) compiler trying to tell me with its hints which follow the error message?

There is no use case behind this, just a person who wants to understand :-) Thanks!

Hans

Comment: `(shared_ptr<base>&)pShDer` -- I'm surprised that this compiles, can you show a [mre]?

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast

Comment: *"Obviously the C-style cast work always, and so does the reinterpret_cast*" - Not surprising, given that the C style cast is secified to eventually try a `reinterpret_cast`. I wouldn't go so far as to say the code "works" though, since its behavior is undefined. You can't just alias object however you want.

Comment: "Obviously the C-style cast work" —- for some loose definition of "work".

Comment: In a case like this I recommend writing a helper function. Makes it a bit easier to read and it's much easier to tell what exactly is happening. Furthermore you can even add an assertion checking for a non-empty smart pointer: https://godbolt.org/z/9fbGsnY9c

Comment: I shouldn't have written "works", but rather "compiles". Though in my special case it did what I expected. But I'll heed the "undefined behaviour" warnings!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<base>&>(pShDer)->Func(); // ok
```

Undefined behavior. You are instructing the compiler to treat a glvalue to a `shared_ptr<derived>` as if it was a glvalue to a `shared_ptr<base>`. Member access through a type that isn't *similar* (i.e. differs only in `const`-qualifications) to the actual type of the referenced object causes undefined behavior.

```
reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<base>const &>(pShDer)->Func(); // ok
```

Also undefined behavior for the same reason as above.

```
((shared_ptr<base>&)pShDer)->Func(); // ok
```

Also undefined behavior since it is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast<shared_ptr<base>&>(pShDer)->Func();`.

```
static_cast<shared_ptr<base>const &>(pShDer)->Func(); // ok
```

This one is ok. It creates a temporary `shared_ptr<base>` object, initialized via constructor call, and `static_cast<shared_ptr<base>const &>(pShDer)` refers to this temporary object.

`std::shared_ptr` has a constructor that allows constructing a `std::shared_ptr<B>` from a `std::shared_ptr<D>` if `D*` can be implicitly converted to `B*`. This is completely safe. `shared_ptr` supports exactly this use case. When the last `shared_ptr` is destroyed, it will always call `delete` on the pointer type with which the original `shared_ptr` was constructed. (Note that `unique_ptr` in contrast deletes through the actual deleter type of the `unique_ptr` instance.)

```
//static_cast<shared_ptr<base>&>(pShDer)->Func();
```

Fails because a non-`const` lvalue reference is not allowed to bind to a temporary object. Consequently `static_cast` is also specified to not allowed the equivalent conversion to a reference type.

> The idea is, I don't construct a temporary shared_ptr and destroy it when the line of code ends,

You are doing exactly that in the `static_cast` case and it is a good thing.

> but rather I want the compiler to treat the existing shared_ptr as if it were a pointer to base.

That's fundamentally not allowed and will always have UB.

```
((unique_ptr<base>&)pUnDer)->Func(); // ok
reinterpret_cast<unique_ptr<base>&>(pUnDer)->Func(); // ok
reinterpret_cast<unique_ptr<base>const&>(pUnDer)->Func(); // ok
```

All of them undefined behavior for the same reasons as with `shared_ptr`.

```
//static_cast<unique_ptr<base>&>(pUnDer)->Func();
```

Doesn't work for the same reason as with `shared_ptr`.

```
//static_cast<unique_ptr<base>const&>(pUnDer)->Func();
```

Doesn't work because you are trying to copy a `unique_ptr` (by creating a temporary object). `unique_ptr` is non-copyable.

It is however movable, so `static_cast<unique_ptr<base>const&>(std::move(pUnDer))->Func();` would work, but would cause the ownership to be transferred to the temporary `unique_ptr` instance, which would then be destroyed at the end of the full-expression and destroy the managed `derived` object with it. This would then also have UB if your `base` didn't have a `virtual` destructor.

---

All in all: Do not use `reinterpret_cast` if you are not 100% sure that you understand what it does in the specific use case. Otherwise you will cause UB. Never use C-style casts because they may sometimes resolve to `reinterpret_cast` (or other casts) and it is sometimes hard to tell whether they are safe.

Comment: I'm not pretending to understand this all at first reading, but the many mentions of undefined behaviour should make me think twice before I try this in productive code. Many thanks to all contributors!